# Error : method gettext() must be call from UI thread is worker

Tags: android

While working on a project I'm getting this error
Error : method gettext() must be call from UI thread is worker
on the following line :

```
String url = Util.send_chat_url+"?email_id="+editText_mail_id.getText().toString()+"&message="+editText_chat_message.getText().toString();
```

Please Help

This is my entire code for the class ChatActivity.java

```
package com.example.ankit.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ankit.myapplication.XmppService;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

//import services.XmppService;


public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText_mail_id;
    EditText editText_chat_message;
    ListView listView_chat_messages;
    Button button_send_chat;
    List<ChatObject> chat_list;

    BroadcastReceiver recieve_chat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        XmppService xm= new XmppService();
        Log.d("pavan","in chat "+getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id"));
        Log.d("pavan","in chat server "+Util.SERVER);
        XmppService.setupAndConnect(ChatActivity.this, Util.SERVER, "",
                getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id"), Util.XMPP_PASSWORD);


        editText_mail_id= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mail_id);
        editText_chat_message= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_chat_message);
        listView_chat_messages= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_chat_messages);
        button_send_chat= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send_chat);
        button_send_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // send chat message to server
                String message=editText_chat_message.getText().toString();

                showChat("sent",message);

                //  new SendMessage().execute();

                XmppService.sendMessage(ChatActivity.this, editText_mail_id.getText().toString() + Util.SUFFIX_CHAT, Message.Type.chat, message);
                editText_chat_message.setText("");


            }
        });


        recieve_chat=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Log.d("pavan","in local braod "+message);
                showChat("recieve",message);


            }
        };

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(recieve_chat, new IntentFilter("message_recieved"));



    }

    private void showChat(String type, String message){

        if(chat_list==null || chat_list.size()==0){

            chat_list= new ArrayList<ChatObject>();
        }

        chat_list.add(new ChatObject(message,type));

        ChatAdabter chatAdabter=new ChatAdabter(ChatActivity.this,R.layout.chat_view,chat_list);

        listView_chat_messages.setAdapter(chatAdabter);
        //chatAdabter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String url = Util.send_chat_url+"?email_id="+editText_mail_id.getText().toString()+"&message="+editText_chat_message.getText().toString();
            Log.i("pavan", "url" + url);

            OkHttpClient client_for_getMyFriends = new OkHttpClient();

            String response = null;
            // String response=Utility.callhttpRequest(url);

            try {
                url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
                response = callOkHttpRequest(new URL(url),
                        client_for_getMyFriends);
                for (String subString : response.split("<script", 2)) {
                    response = subString;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Toast.makeText(context,"response "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }


    }



    // Http request using OkHttpClient
    String callOkHttpRequest(URL url, OkHttpClient tempClient)
            throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection = tempClient.open(url);

        connection.setConnectTimeout(40000);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            // Read the response.
            in = connection.getInputStream();
            byte[] response = readFully(in);
            return new String(response, "UTF-8");
        } finally {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
    }

    byte[] readFully(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }








}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Pass editText_mail_id.getText() and editText_chat_message.getText() as parameters to your async task or set it in onPreExecute to some variable

Like :

```
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String mailId;
    private String msgText;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mailId = editText_mail_id.getText().toString();
        msgText = editText_chat_message.getText().toString();

    }
```

Change url in doInBackground as :

```
String url = Util.send_chat_url+"?email_id="+mailId+"&message="+msgText;
```

Comment: If you are inside an Activity, you could also access the UI thread using runOnUiThread.

Answer (score 0):

you can create class for storing your parameter like i do,

Just create one class

example :

```
public class MyTaskParams
{
    String mailId;
    String message;

    public MyTaskParams(String mailId, String message)
    {
        this.mailId = mailId;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, String {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
    String mailId = params[0].mailId;
    String message = params[0].message;
    String url = Util.send_chat_url+"?email_id="+ mailId +"&message="+ message;        
    }
}
```

so you can just call like this

```
MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(editText_mail_id.getText().toString(),editText_chat_message.getText().toString());

SendMessage myTask = new SendMessage();
myTask.execute(params);
```

with this code you can call SendMessage Class from any activity, dont bind your asynctask with get text because if you do that you just can use SendMessage only in that activity
Hope this can help you.